# Forcing a reload of a dynamically linked library

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I am using a dynamically linked 3rd party library that has a side effect:

When calling a function from inside the library it saves a state.
this can cause the library to return different answers (although logically the same) when calling the same functions over and over.

What I want to do is to reload the library to memory: forcing it to lose all the state and start a clean page - this way, every time I call the library i will get the exact reply.

I assume that one way is to use dlopen/dlclose and this will probably cleanup any previously saved state in the library - on each dlopen it will reload the library to memory.

however, it complicates the code if I have many calls to the library (i now need to use dlsym for each function call and etc.)

is there a magic way to reload a specific/all libraries to memory? when i will access the library again it will reload it to memory (on demand - just like on fresh start).

Thanks,
Itay

Comment: No magic way. You need to `dlopen`. Read [Drepper's: Howto write shared libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper.

Comment: thanks for the paper - seems very intresting...